# xcodebuild code sign failing with unknown error

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

```
xcodebuild archive -workspace **** -configuration Release -scheme **** -archivePath ****
```

The above shell command is ending with a codesign error below. I have checked the presence of relevant provisioning profiles and certificates in the system. Any help is greatly appreciated.

> /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign
>   513C0AFCECE1080F30CC63A1EC79CF25211727EA --entitlements
>   /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/****-avloytojkryrlfcniwothqvllyzi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/****/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/****.build/Release-iphoneos/****.build/****.appex.xcent
>   --timestamp=none /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/****-avloytojkryrlfcniwothqvllyzi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/****/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/****.appex
>   /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/****-avloytojkryrlfcniwothqvllyzi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/****/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/****.appex:
>   unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff Command /usr/bin/codesign failed
>   with exit code 1

Comment: delete DerivedData  & reset profiles in build settings and then build the project and archive it.

Comment: You can also get more output from codesign by using the -v option

Comment: @ablarg that's a good input. Will try it out.