# Suddenly Xcode 9 can't sign my iOS app

Tags: ios, code-signing, xcode9

I released a major update to my iOS app about 3 months ago. I've released five updates since then with no difficulty. Before releasing the sixth, I took about six weeks to work on another task. When I came back to Xcode -- same machine, same code, same project, same everything -- I suddenly get this error when trying to do an Archive build to upload to the App Store:

```
/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bfvmmuvzjmellabypwoqwijttzeh/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp 4/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47409423) which suggested I update my keychain password. It suggests I select "Login" and then "Change password for keychain 'login'". When I do that, nothing happens. I mean, I don't get a dialog in which I can enter a password. It just doesn't do anything.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48296751/422156) which suggested I delete my DerivedData. I deleted the folder under DerivedData for MyApp. No change. Still get the same error.

Thinking of getting a job as a Walmart greeter. Those guys always seem so happy.

Comment: Did the project build successfully ? With code sign ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting this question I saw another that suggested simply rebooting. So I restarted my MacBook and now it works.